# MacBook Pro: OS X reinstall is taking "forever", (over 12 hours) to finish

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

This is my first time ever dealing with a Mac OS X reinstallation.
About a week ago, while working online, my MacBook Pro just started to be very very slow to do anything. I would get the WHEEL spinning for over a minute for each click on anything.

I looked for trouble shooting info and followed the procedures to use disk utility, etc. No issues with hardware were reported.
I only had like 3 issues with registry entries I believe.

I decided to backup my important files....took me 3 days because each click would take ages to be executed.

Now for over 18 hours, I'm waiting on OS X Mavericks to finish installing on my computer which is under 2 yrs old. 
Oh, after the initial stage of 'installation', the download and install, which took like 4 hrs, the computer rebooted (as was expected according to videos on yt).
However instead of going to the setup page, it went back to installation window which was supposed to take 24 mins initially but I'm still waiting 4 hrs later.

Is this common with Macs?

If not, what's the problem with this Mac and how can I fix this please?

I get the long wheel spinning even during this reinstallation and I'm totally baffled by this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is not normal to take that long. You might have a hardware problem wit the disk or memory or even CPU. It could be also a problem with your osx. Difficult to say with current information. Unplug any external devices. Do you think you have a Virus? What screen do you have displaying? Press and hold the Power button for 5 seconds then relase and restart.

Answer (score 3):

This is not common.  I have never had this problem and I upgrade to every new version.

I always create a bootable USB installer.  Here are the instructions from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856.  This will let you check your disk and reformat.  I always reformat so that I know everything is the way it is supposed to be, but it is a bit more time consuming.

Comment: Yeah it is actually pretty common...

Answer (score 3):

What is your installation source?  Are you installing via just the recovery partition?  If so, it's technically installing over the internet.  In other words, it's copying a ~5 GB installation via the internet.  If you put Mavericks on a thumb drive, then your only limitation is the speed of your USB bus.

I'd suggest pulling down the installer on another Mac and [creating a local installation source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856).  Installing it over the internet is a multi-hour process.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since the question has been asked, but this response is for the sake of anyone landing here through a google search or some such.

This is a known problem with the Apple Store for both iOS and Mac OS X. The solution is to change your DNS settings and flush your DNS cache. There seems to be something funny with apple's CDN.

For more details check out this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/3n0aj9/el_capitan_is_downloading_very_slow). To flush your DNS Cache (so that the settings change takes immediate effect) you need to run the following in a terminal (on OS X 10.9 or newer):

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

or the following for OS X 10.8 or older:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```